# Android Minesweeper algorithm

Tags: java, android, windows, 2d-games

I'm developing a game "Minesweeper" for Andoid on Java and I have a problem when opening the cells. How to make sure that I click on the cell opened adjacent empty cells? (How it is done in Miner for Windows).
Introduction: I have an array which i receive from bluetooth socket stream. Array like this :

```
1 9 1 0
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

9-is a mine
0-is blank cell
1-nearest mines count

After that i calculate game field

```
array = Model.getGameField();
int size = array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    ((TableRow) table.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(j).setTag(array[i][j] + "");
}
```

OnClick function :

```
if (iWantToSetFlag == 0)
                {
                    tmpBtn = ((Button) v);
                    if (!(tmpBtn.getTag().equals("9")))
                    {
                        OpenButtons(tmpBtn.getId() / 10,     tmpBtn.getId() % 10);
                        recreateTable();
                    }
                    else
                        startLose();
            }
            else
            {
                if (((Button) v).getText().equals("M"))
                    ((Button) v).setText("");
                else
                    ((Button) v).setText("M");
            }
```

I have a function

```
    private void OpenButtons(int x, int y)
    {
        array[x][y] = -1;
                    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
        {
            for (int k1 = 1; k1 >= -1; k1--)
            {
                    if (x + k >= 0 && x + k < array.length && y - k1 >= 0 && y - k1 < array[x + k].length)
                        if (array[x + k][y - k1] == 0)
                            OpenButtons(x + k, y - k1);
            }
        }

    }
```

which recursively open cells but i have a StackOverFlow error. Help please.

Comment: `"...which recursively open cells but i have a StackOverFlow error. Help please."` -- which usually means to me that you have a problem with your stopping condition in the recursion.

Comment: By the way, ignoring array index out of bounds is a bad idea; a very, ***very*** bad idea.

Comment: But i don't ignore it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: +1, good parenting :)

Comment: `But i don't ignore it.`  Yes you do.  You catch the exception, then do nothing about it.  Even worse, in this instance, an array index out of bounds can only be caused by a coding error.

Comment: @MihaiDanila: thanks. At least I didn't smack him on the bottom.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I do not quite understand what the problem is here. The exception is triggered, but I do not need to do anything in it really. Or should I?

Comment: The point is that you trigger an exception because you have not correctly set the indices in your loops.  This in turn is because you have not checked for the edge cases.  If you are at an edge, you should not try to test -1, or edge +1.  If nothing else, knowingly creating an exception is (nearly always) really bad practice and will hit performance hard since you will generate a lot of these in your main UI thread.  Bad, bad, bad.

Comment: You should never have empty catch blocks as that means that you are ignoring an exception. But in this situation you shouldn't even catch the AIOOBE (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) as when this occurs, it means that there is a bad bug in your program. **Edit**: as @Simon explains much better than me.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Actually, I worded that badly `knowingly creating` an exception is usually good practice.  Knowingly *causing* an exception is usually bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling your recursion with changed parameters:

```
if (array[x + k][y - k1] == 0)
    OpenButtons(x + k, y - k1);
```

And of course, as has been mentioned in the comments of the question, you should check for the array bounds yourself instead of just ignoring the exceptions:

```
if (x + k >= 0 && x + k < array.length &&
    y - k1 >= 0 && y - k1 < array[x + k].length) { ...
```

put before your other `if`-clause will only check fields which actually *exist*. Ridding you of your malicious empty `try-catch`.

---

Since the recursive algorithm will still cause a `StackOverflowException` for large fields, an iterative algorithm might be better suited here.

```
private void OpenButtons(int x, int y) {
    Queue<Point> toOpen = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    toOpen.add(new Point(x, y));
    array[x][y] = -1;
    while (!toOpen.isEmpty()) {
        Point p = toOpen.poll();
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++) {
            for (int k1 = 1; k1 >= -1; k1--) {
                if (x + k >= 0 && x + k < array.length && y - k1 >= 0
                        && y - k1 < array[x + k].length)
                    if (array[x + k][y - k1] == 0) {
                        array[x + k][y - k1] = -1;
                        toOpen.add(new Point(x + k, y - k1));
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i don't exit from recursion. but how to exit from it?

Comment: Even better if you include the bounds check in the for statement - something like `for (int k = x == 0 ? 0 : x-1; k < x = arrayLength -1 ? x : x +1 ; k++)`

Comment: Nothing to do with optimization.  Everything to do with adding bounds checks into the statement which creates the indices.  Voila, no out of bounds exception.

Comment: @PANDA: there are no stupid questions. There are poorly presented questions that are difficult to answer because they may be incomplete or two broad, but your question is not one of these, and again is certainly not stupid.

Comment: @PANDA the example board from your question does work for me. You could try debugging your error by printing the coordinates at the beginning of your `OpenButtons` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels,I change my code but Exception still throws.Maybe i don't exit from recursion. but how to exit from it?

Comment: @PANDA your recursion should exit quite well because you're checking for the field value being `0` and changing all values to `-1` when uncovering.

Comment: @PANDA Okay, I'm sorry - using this algorithm you will run into a `StackOverflowException` for larger fields (100x100 on my PC) because you potentially open every field in a new recursion layer. You'll need to restructure your algorithm to supporter larger minefields.

Comment: @MichaelLang so how it doit? :)

Comment: @Simon it seems that the algorithm used in your source also uses the same recursive algorithm as posted by the OP and is consequently also not scalable enough for large fields.

Comment: This is hometask for take job in company. I have a time up to tomorrow :(